# Get only IP Address from given string

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following given string formats.

```
DECLARE @IPData_1 nvarchar(max) = '{"ODBC":"Connection-StringIPX-IP=10.60.96.230&X-Local}'
DECLARE @IPData_2 nvarchar(max) = '{"ODBC":"Connection-StringIPX-IP:1.60.0.230X-Local=1}'
DECLARE @IPData_3 nvarchar(max) = '{"ODBC":"Connection-StringIPX-For=233.60.255.120TransactionID:2}'
DECLARE @IPData_4 nvarchar(max) = '{"ODBC":"Connection-StringIPX-For:1.1.1.90ID=1}'
```

I want to get only IP Address that is:

```
10.60.96.230
1.60.0.230
233.60.255.120
1.1.1.90
```

My try:

```
SELECT
    SUBSTRING(@IPData_1,CHARINDEX('IPX-IP=',@IPData_1)+7,CHARINDEX('.',@IPData_1)),
    SUBSTRING(@IPData_1,CHARINDEX('IPX-IP:',@IPData_1)+7,CHARINDEX('.',@IPData_1)),
    SUBSTRING(@IPData_1,CHARINDEX('IPX-For=',@IPData_1)+7,CHARINDEX('.',@IPData_1)),
    SUBSTRING(@IPData_1,CHARINDEX('IPX-For:',@IPData_1)+7,CHARINDEX('.',@IPData_1))
```

Comment: have you investigated regex?

Comment: how does that help in SQL Server with no (native) regex?

Comment: Ths format is really entertaining: Almost JSON except no closing quote, and multiple pieces of info per value. TLDR don't roll your own format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL Server is not the optimal place to perform string manipulation.

Having said that, sometimes we don't have the option to do so elsewhere.

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE (IPData NVARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @Table (IPData) VALUES
('{"ODBC":"Connection-StringIPX-IP=10.60.96.230&X-Local}'),
('{"ODBC":"Connection-StringIPX-IP:1.60.0.230X-Local=1}'),
('{"ODBC":"Connection-StringIPX-For=233.60.255.120TransactionID:2}'),
('{"ODBC":"Connection-StringIPX-For:1.1.1.90ID=1}');      

SELECT IPData, SUBSTRING(IPData, PATINDEX('%[IP|FOR][:|=]%', IPData)+2, PATINDEX('%[0-9][&|X|T|ID]%', IPData)-(PATINDEX('%[IP|FOR][:|=]%', IPData))-1) AS IPData
  FROM @Table;
```

| IPData | IPData |
| --- | --- |
| {"ODBC":"Connection-StringIPX-IP=10.60.96.230&X-Local} | 10.60.96.230 |
| {"ODBC":"Connection-StringIPX-IP:1.60.0.230X-Local=1} | 1.60.0.230 |
| {"ODBC":"Connection-StringIPX-For=233.60.255.120TransactionID:2} | 233.60.255.120 |
| {"ODBC":"Connection-StringIPX-For:1.1.1.90ID=1} | 1.1.1.90 |

Here we are using the [`PATINDEX` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/patindex-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) to find the locations of patterns, and using [`SUBSTRING`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/substring-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) to create a substring using those pattern locations.